# Is there a way to check, from C#, if SSRS Reporting Server is running?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to check whether a SSRS Report Server is running before I generate the reports for my website. I am trying to stay away from using a try catch in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two modes to deploy a SSRS report.
One is through sharepoint and one is through native.

If you're **NOT** deployed through sharepoint, you could check if a SSRS server is running by sending an http request and examining the response.

I got this information from : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143773.aspx#bkmk_nativemode

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178811.aspx

Comment: I think I am going to go with the HTTP request.

Comment: Is there a way I can check it through an SQL script?